# Trying to make an AJAX call on my gh pages website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github-pages

I have this code:

```
function getAllImgs(){
console.log("1");
$.ajax({
  url: "../img/wood/",
  function(data){
    var parser = new DOMParser(),
        doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

    var rows = doc.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('tr');

    for (var i=1;i<rows.length;i++) {
      populateImgs(rows[i].children[3].children[0].text);
    }
  }
});
  };


 function populateImgs(url){
    console.log("2");
    $.ajax({
      url: "../img/wood/"+url,
      success: function(imgData){
        var imgParser = new DOMParser(),
            imgDoc = imgParser.parseFromString(imgData, 'text/html');

        var imgRows = imgDoc.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('tr')

        for(var r = 0; r < imgRows.length; r++){
          if (imgRows[r].children[2]) {
            if (parseInt(imgRows[r].children[2].innerText)>0){
              $("#photoIcons").append("<div class='card' style='background-image:url(/img/wood/"+url+imgRows[r].children[3].children[0].text+");' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#imgModal' data-url='/img/wood/"+url+imgRows[r].children[3].children[0].text+"'></div>");
            };
          }
        }
      }
    })
  };
```

This works great on my local test server.  I get all folders within my `img/wood/` folder and then populate my gallery with every file/image within every folder.  On the gallery there is the ability to filter to only one of the folders.  However when I try to upload this to github pages, I get a 404 error stating that the `img/wood/` folder does not exist, therefore not able to access any of the folders or images within.  I've tried tweaking the url and even putting the direct link in and it does not seem to work.  Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: obvious question...does that folder exist on your github pages site? Can you visit it directly? Is it deployed in the same position relative to your page, as on your local machine? You haven't actually confirmed, in the question, whether you've checked this or not.

Comment: Yes the folders and files exist on my master branch which I am using for my pages website and are in the same position as locally.  However I also cannot visit these files directly.

Comment: Well that is definitely going to cause a problem, not just with your code . They exist but you can't access them. What happens when you try and access them directly?

Comment: It displays a 404 file not found from github.

Comment: So that means your URL is wrong. Either you're looking in the wrong place, or the files really are not there. Since you said they're definitely there, then I assume you're looking in the wrong place. But...if you can see that they're there, then presumably you know the URL for them??

Comment: We'll maybe there is something I'm missing.  But they are there in the correct spot within the repository.  Exactly how I have the file structure locally.  But the URL doesn't link to it the way it seems it should.

Comment: do you mind sharing the URLs of your GitHub page, and also the URL to where you can view the files in the online version of the repository (i.e. via the GitHub website)?

Comment: https://github.com/nasnyder91/wood-portfolio?files=1   https://nasnyder91.github.io/wood-portfolio/

Comment: https://github.com/nasnyder91/wood-portfolio/tree/master/img/wood/Bowls is the URL for your Bowls folder, as can be seen trivially by simply browsing to it by clicking on the folder links until you reach it (having started at https://github.com/nasnyder91/wood-portfolio?files=1). But your app is trying to reach https://nasnyder91.github.io/img/wood/Bowls/ which doesn't exist. So you need to prepend "wood-portfolio/tree/master/" to the URL you're using in the ajax when it's published on GitHub.

Comment: But even once you do that, you could have trouble with the DOMParser because the HTML page structure you get back from visiting that link isn't the same as you'll be getting from your local server, so you can't assume that `imgDoc.querySelector('table')` will find the correct table, or any table at all. At the moment it does look, from a brief glance at the page source, like it might work, but GitHub could change the structure of the page at any time and it's out of your control. This is quite a naive and brittle approach to fetching files from a folder.

Comment: Ok so what would be your recommended way of doing this?   I wanted it so the contents of the folder can change at any time and will still display correctly

Comment: Ideally you'd have a server-side language with an API call which would fetch a list of the filenames in JSON format which you could then loop through, rather than relying on a webserver-specific (and permissions-dependent) HTML folder listings page. Also I'm not sure GitHub pages is the best way to host your site - it's meant to let you host project pages related to the code, like intros, documentation etc, it's not intended to be a place to actually demo the finished product. It's not designed as a hosting environment in that way, hence why you have things like this URL issue.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.  I'll look into that

Comment: Is this issues solved? I am facing the same issue